# Testing setState anonymous function call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

Consider the following button in JSX:

```
interface Props {
  index: number;
  setIndex: Dispatch<SetStateAction<number>>;
}

export function Button({ index, setIndex }: Props) {
  return (
    <button
      type="button"
      data-testid="prev_btn"
      onClick={() => setIndex(prevIndex => prevIndex - 1)}
    >
      Previous
    </button>
  );
}
```

I would like to write a test in Jest / React Testing Library that renders the button and passes `setIndex` in as a prop, and then checks that `setIndex` is called with the correct value. For example:

```
const mockSetIndex = jest.fn();
const mockProps = {
  setIndex: mockSetIndex,
  index: 1,
};

describe('Button test', () => {
  it('should update the index when the "previous" button is clicked', () => {
    const { getByTestId } = render(<Button {...mockProps} />);
    const prevBtn = getByTestId('prev_btn');

    userEvent.click(prevBtn);

    expect(mockSetIndex).toBeCalledWith(0);
  });
});
```

The result I get is a failure with:

```
    expect(jest.fn()).toBeCalledWith(...expected)

    Expected: 0
    Received: [Function anonymous]
```

There is another instance of a similar button that *increments* the index, so I would like to test that the correct behaviour is being made with both buttons.

Comment: Does the component you're testing actually get setIndex from props? Give a [mre].

Comment: It does get it from props.

Comment: OK, and how exactly does `mockSetActiveSearchResultIndex` connect to everything else? Are `Button` and `ButtonForm` the same thing? You should provide an example someone could drop into a vanilla CRA `--template typescript` app and run to recreate the issue.

Comment: But basically you're calling `setIndex` with `prevIndex => prevIndex - 1`, **not** `0`, so it's unclear why you chose that expectation. It seems like you're testing something that's driven by a `useState` in a parent, in which case it should probably also be _tested_ in that context rather than mocked out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `setIndex` with a function and not a number.  While this is an acceptable argument for `setIndex`, it's not what you're testing.  Either change your function to something like

```
interface Props {
  index: number;
  setIndex: Dispatch<SetStateAction<number>>;
}

export function Button({ index, setIndex }: Props) {
  return (
    <button
      type="button"
      data-testid="prev_btn"
      onClick={() => setIndex(index - 1)}
    >
      Previous
    </button>
  );
}
```

or test that it's passing a function that has the expected behavior

```
describe('Button test', () => {
  it('should update the index when the "previous" button is clicked', () => {
    const { getByTestId } = render(<Button {...mockProps} />);
    const prevBtn = getByTestId('prev_btn');

    userEvent.click(prevBtn);

    const passedFunction = mockProps.setIndex.mock.calls[0][0]

    expect(passedFunction(1)).toEqual(0);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on the properties of `Button`, I'd guess its usage looks something like this:

```
const Parent = () => {
  const [index, setIndex] = useState(1);
  return (
    <>
      <Button index={index} setIndex={setIndex} />
      <p data-testid="current_index">Current index: {index}</p>
    </>
  );
};
```

This gives the `Parent` no control over its own state, the `Button` could call e.g. `setIndex(100)` whether or not that has any practical meaning. Passing a setter directly to another component is generally a code smell for this reason.

---

A less tightly coupled structure, where `Parent` is responsible for its own state, would look like this:

```
const Parent = () => {
  const [index, setIndex] = useState(1);

  const decrement = () => setIndex((previousIndex) => previousIndex - 1);

  return (
    <>
      <p>Current index: {index}</p>
      <Button onClick={decrement} />
    </>
  );
};
```

This is *much* easier to test:

```
describe("Button", () => {
  it("should signal when the Previous button is clicked", () => {
    const onClick = jest.fn();
    render(<Button onClick={onClick} />);

    userEvent.click(screen.getByRole("button", { name: /previous/i }));

    expect(onClick).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

*(Note I'm following the [priority guide](https://testing-library.com/docs/queries/about#priority) to use user-facing, accessible selectors as much as possible.)*

---

Alternatively, if `Button` is *only* used within the `Parent` (as the high level of coupling on state suggests), test it in that context:

```
describe("Parent", () => {
  it("should allow the previous thing to be selected", () => {
    render(<Parent />);

    userEvent.click(screen.getByRole("button", { name: /previous/i }));

    // assert on actual outcome of index changing, e.g.
    expect(screen.getByTestId("current_index")).toHaveTextContent("Current index: 0");
  });
});
```

In this case, testing at the boundary *between* `Button` and its `Parent` isn't really appropriate. To indicate this coupling you could move the `Button` into the module where `Parent` is defined, and **not** export it for separate access - treat the fact that the button has been extracted to a separate component as an *implementation detail*.