# Jest test returning [function anonymous] when testing setState hook

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

I asked this question previously, but this time I've created a minimal reproducible example.

Below is my App, which contains an object state, and renders a Sidebar component:

```
import Sidebar from './Sidebar';
import { useState } from 'react';

function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    status: 'ok',
    count: 0,
  });
  return <Sidebar state={state} setState={setState} />;
}

export default App;
```

Here is my Sidebar component, which takes the `count` property from the `state` object, and updates the `count` property when the user clicks the button:

```
export default function Sidebar({ state, setState }) {
  function handleButtonClick() {
    setState((prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
      count: prevState.count + 1,
    }));
  }
  return (
    <>
      <div>count: {state.count} </div>
      <button data-testid='button' onClick={handleButtonClick}>
        Increase Count
      </button>
    </>
  );
}
```

Below is the Jest test for my Sidebar. I've mocked the `state` and `setState`, and am expecting `setState` to be called with the object after the user clicks the 'Increase Count' button:

```
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import userEvent from '@testing-library/user-event';
import Sidebar from './Sidebar';

let state = () => ({
  status: 'ok',
  count: 0,
});
const setState = jest.fn();

test('sets count on button click', () => {
  render(<Sidebar state={state} setState={setState} />);

  const button = screen.getByTestId('button');
  userEvent.click(button);
  expect(setState).toHaveBeenCalledWith({ status: 'ok', count: 1 });
});
```

However, below is the result of me running the Sidebar test. It receives `[Function anonymous]`.
[image]

I'm not sure if this is because my `expect` is written incorrectly, or because I didn't mock `state`/`setState` properly. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Firstly I would suggest you look at the code you're testing - what _is_ `setState` called with? Is it an object, or a function? But secondly I would suggest _not_ mocking parts of React's API, as you don't own that, or giving `Sidebar` uncontrolled access to `App`'s state - maybe it _should_ be calling the parent back with the object, and letting the parent manage merging that into the state.

Comment: Hi @jonrsharpe, ah, I see it's being called with a function, that's my first mistake... How would I 'not' mock the getter and setter functions though?

Comment: I am trying to wrap my ```Sidebar``` component inside ```App``` in the test rendering, but ```Sidebar``` still requires ```state``` and ```setState```, I'm not sure where to provide them besides mocking them in the test like I've already done:
```render( <App><Sidebar state={state} setState={setState} /></App>);
```

Comment: If you render `Sidebar` inside `App` then _`App`_ provides those props, and _nothing_ needs mocking. What you're doing is providing children to `App` it doesn't deal with at all, an _additional_ `Sidebar`. Or you can refactor such that you own the API between `App` and `Sidebar`, rather than using React's, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/71749161/3001761.

Comment: oh yes, no need to include Sidebar as a child then, is there? But, I thought the best practice is to have a test for every major component of an application. If I'm now replacing ```Sidebar``` with ```App```, I'm now testing ```App```, not ```Sidebar``` any longer.

Comment: But with the structure you currently have `App` and `Sidebar` are fundamentally coupled. So you either test them together, and treat the split as an implementation detail not a boundary to test at, or _actually_ decouple them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, don't mock `setState` or the React API. These are [implementation details](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/testing-implementation-details) of your components, so testing them is against the RTL philosophy.

It's an antipattern to pass state setters and getters directly into child components because it couples the parent and child's implementations too tightly, stifling refactoring. The child knows too much about the parent (that it uses state hooks, as well as `status` which it never uses) and is responsible for too much (modifying the parent's state correctly).

Specifically, move `handleButtonClick` to the parent and pass it down as a prop. This hides the `setState` call, decoupling the components from the hooks API and making it impossible for the child to corrupt the parent's state with a malformed `setState` call. It also gives the parent power over when to re-render.

In your simplified example, there's no reason for `App` to control this state since it's never rendered anywhere except for the one child that also sets it. I assume `App` needs access to the data elsewhere, preventing you from being able to lower the state into the child and eliminate the prop.

One litmus test for coupling is asking "if I were to refactor class components to functional components or vice-versa, would I have to rewrite all of my tests?" If the answer is yes, you're testing implementation details.

After making your handler generic, you can still mock it and assert that it was called. However, the better (though not mutually-exclusive) test is to render the parent and the child and simply assert that the user-visible effect occurred after the button click. This tests the handler and gives full coverage without mocking, with the "drawback" that your unit of code is now 2 components working in tandem. This is acceptable since that's the distance the state spans anyway, so the test might as well acknowledge that as the unit under test.

Comment: Thanks very much for all the advice. I've removed all state setters from the props of sub-components to help decouple them from their parents somewhat. The biggest downside to this is that I've had to move all my input change functions (which call the setters with the input values) into the App component, which makes the App seem crowded with functions that look like they should all be in the Sidebar component. Unfortunately, it seems like I have to choose between putting functions outside the component where they seem to belong, or making state setters into component props.

Comment: Now I'm struggling to mock the api calls that App uses, but that's a different question

Comment: API calls are good to mock. If the App component seems bloated and you can't move any state into its children, try splitting it into smaller sub-components. I don't know your larger app context, but if you need a ton of global state and there aren't any good cut points for the App component's state, context or redux might be a solution. Anyway, I'd rather have a bloated App that fully controls its own state than a leaner one where its state setters are controlled by its children.

Comment: That's an interesting thought, I never realized control over one's state is so important. I'm going to refactor my code to match that. I've used some context already, but I'll consider splitting up App into sub-components as well. thanks for all your help @ggorlen

Comment: Maybe this will help motivate it: imagine you have a bug where something isn't rerendering when it should, or you have a wrong value in state. Would you rather debug an app where those state modifications are happening in any one of a few nested child components, or an app where all of that state is only modified within the parent component itself, and child components can only communicate through the parent's interface? It's sort of like getters and setters to protect private variables from the OOP world, instead of classes being able to mess with one another's internal state directly.